# How to safely replace a not-yet-failed disk in a Linux RAID5 array?

Tags: linux, software-raid, mdadm, raid5

I have a software RAID5 array (Linux md) on 4 disks.

**I would like to replace one of the disks with a new one, without putting the array in a degraded state**, and if possible, online. How would that be possible?

It's important because I don't want to:

- take the risk of stressing the other disks so one may crash during rebuild,
- take the risk of being in a "no-parity state" so I don't have a safety net for some time.

I suppose doing so online is too much asking and I should just raw copy (`dd`) the data of the old disk to the new one *offline* and then replace it, but I think it is theoretically possible...

*Some context*: Those disks have all been spinning almost continuously for more than 5.5 years. They still work perfectly for the moment and they all pass the (long) SMART self-test. However, I have reasons to think that one of those 4 disks will not last much longer (supposed predictive failure).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### Using mdadm 3.3+

Since [`mdadm` 3.3](https://github.com/neilbrown/mdadm/commit/70c55e36b73827579fcb2dadbb6359ef605191ff) (released 2013, Sep 3), if you have a [3.2+ kernel](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=2d78f8c451785f030ac1676a18691896b59c69d8), you can proceed as follows:

```
# mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdc1
# mdadm /dev/md0 --replace /dev/sdd1 --with /dev/sdc1
```

`sdd1` is the device you want to replace, `sdc1` is the preferred device to do so and must be declared as a spare on your array.

The `--with` option is optional, if not specified, any available spare will be used.

### Older mdadm version

*Note: You still need a [3.2+ kernel](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=2d78f8c451785f030ac1676a18691896b59c69d8).*

First, add a new drive as a spare (replace `md0` and `sdc1` with your RAID and disk device, respectively):

```
# mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdc1
```

Then, initiate a copy-replace operation like this (`sdd1` being the failing device):

```
# echo want_replacement > /sys/block/md0/md/dev-sdd1/state
```

### Result

The system will copy all readable blocks from `sdd1` to `sdc1`. If it comes to an unreadable block, it will reconstruct it from parity. Once the operation is complete, the former spare (here: `sdc1`) will become active, and the failing drive will be marked as failed (F) so you can remove it.

*Note:* credit goes to *frostschutz* and *Ansgar Esztermann* who found the original solution (see the [duplicate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102492/#102499)).

### Older kernels

Other answers suggest:

- *Johnny*'s [approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74930): convert array to RAID6, "replace" the disk, then back to RAID5,
- *Hauke Laging*'s [approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74936): briefly remove the disk from the RAID5 array, make it part of a RAID1 (mirror) with the new disk and add that mirror drive back to the RAID5 array (theoretical)...

Comment: `mdadm --add` is still needed before `--replace` will work.  (`mdadm` 3.3, Ubuntu 15.10).  If you do the `--add` after `--replace`, copying will begin as soon as a spare is added.  (The device stays marked as "wanting replacement").

Comment: I'd definitely go with convert to RAID6 with a new disk and then go back to RAID5 without the old disk. This allows keeping at least full RAID5 parity *at all times* and the new RAID6 parity is computed from all existing data so it can be read from all the existing disks instead of causing extra load to only one of the disks. As your intent to replace the oldest disks, using that old disk as the only source for rebuilding new disk is causing maximum stress for that part.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind running RAID-6 (2 parity disks rather than 1), and if you're running mdadmin 3.1.x or higher, you could [convert your RAID-5 array to RAID-6](https://serverfault.com/questions/351240/convert-linux-software-raid-from-raid5-to-raid6) to add an additional parity disk. This will will place the array under stress during the rebuild, however. And it has some performance implications since there are more parity disks to update during writes.

But if it completes successfully, then you can keep your failing disk in place and when it ultimately fails, you've still got parity protection for the array. I think you can conver the array from RAID6 back to RAID5 if you don't wait to keep it as RAID6.

I don't know of an online way to keep the array as RAID-5 and replace the disk without putting the array in degraded mode,  as I think you have to mark it as failed to replace it. Your dd copy idea might be the way to do that.

Comment: @haukelaging FYI it is now possible since kernel 3.2, see [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74924/how-to-safely-replace-a-not-yet-failed-disk-in-a-linux-raid5-array#104052).

Comment: I would consider this as the lowest possible risk because you have fully working RAID5 while building the RAID6 from it. All the other offered solutions either copy from a single device only (causing lots of stress for it) or temporarily disable even RAID5 which means you get instant data loss if any one device fails during the operation.

Answer (score 4):

This may be possible meeting the requirements

1. online
2. don't stress any disk except for the one which is to be replaced

But even if the following may work you will probably not find any recommendation of that kind "in the books"...

Idea:

1. Take disk OLD out of the array (for a short moment): `mdadm --manage /dev/raid5 --fail /dev/OLD`
2. Create a new md device (RAID-1) from disks OLD and NEW: `mdadm --build /dev/md42 --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 /dev/OLD /dev/NEW`
3. Put the RAID-1 back in the array (instead of /dev/OLD): `mdadm --manage /dev/raid5 --re-add /dev/md42`

What **should** :-) happen:

1. The RAID-5 gets /dev/md42 in sync. This should not take long.
2. The RAID-5 is normally operational again (but slower).
3. /dev/NEW is synced with /dev/OLD.

Watch the sync progress (`cat /proc/mdstat` or `mdadm --monitor`). If the sync is finished take the RAID-1 out of the RAID-5, stop the RAID-1, re-add /dev/NEW to the RAID-5. If everything is fine, overwrite the mdraid superblocks on /dev/OLD in order to avoid problems: `mdadm --zero-superblock`

**Warning:** The fast RAID-5 sync may work only if you use a bitmap. If you don't have one then better make a test with a dummy RAID-5 (without a bitmap) first. Or add one. At least adding an external one should be possible. Otherwise it may be necessary to stop the RAID-5 before changing the devices. If you boot from the RAID-5 this would become a bit complicated, though.